# Real Analysis giving a counterexample of measurable sets, and showing a measure is zero.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For #1 I am able to prove it but I am not sure what kind of example can be used and how I would prove that it would fail.

For #2, I am not sure how to go about it.

1) Let $\{A_n\}$ be an infinite sequence of measurable sets increasing to A. Prove that $m(A)=\lim_{n\to \infty} m(A_n)$. Give an example showing that the corresponding statement fails for decreasing sequences of measurable sets.

2) Let $\{I_n\}$, $1\leq n \lt \infty$, be a sequence of intervals with $m(I_n)=\frac{1}{2^n}$. Show that the set of real numbers contained in an infinite number of $I_n$ has measure zero.

Answer (score 1):

For I, as an example try $A_n = [n, \infty) \subset \mathbb{R}$ in the Lebesgue measure. For decreasing subsets it *is* true when one of the $A_n$ (and hence almost all of them) has finite measure. This comes in useful for the next part.

The set of those $x$ can be written as $\cap_{n=1}^\infty \cup_{k = n}^\infty I_n$ (it's called the lim sup of the $I_n$). Now estimate the measure of the unions, and compute the measure of the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for 2: If $f_n$ are nonnegative and measurable, then

$$ \int \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n \, dm =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int f_n \, dm $$

by the MCT. Apply this to $f_n=\chi_{I_n}.$